# How to programmatically connect internet via datacard with AT commands?

Tags: java, ubuntu, at-command

I have a datacard ZTE MF190. I want to use AT commands to register in 2G or 3G and access internet via datacard. Found this  article about [how to make data call](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/data-call-at-commands-to-set-up-gprsedgeumtslte-data-call/):

```
AT+cgatt=1
AT+CGDCONT=1,”IP”,”epc.tmobile.com” //I used my operator PDP context
AT+CGACT=1,1
```

But ping from OS terminal shows 100% package loss.
I've tried on Ubuntu 14 and Windows 7.

How can I connect internet with AT commands using datacard on Ubuntu?

#### UPDATE

I gave bounty to @tripleee's answer because it's more full than first one and answered all my questions. But I'm not satisfied with answers, so I'll answer my own question in a week.

In my answer I'll show how to handle this process with Java. So, please do not move this question to other Stack Exchange websites.

Comment: Your device is made mainly for Russian market. You are better to ask on ru.SO :) Another issue is that it's rated at 7Mbps whereas modern devices can process up to 150Mbps

Comment: @Oceinic, I think it's not a modem problem. It works with dashboard. I tried to sniff USB port but on this case dashboard can not connect because of busy port.

Comment: Not a programming question. This should be migrated to https://superuser.com/ (or maybe https://serverfault.com/?) once the bounty closes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know [wvdial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wvdial) uses [ppp daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_daemon) to connect to the internet using modem. **wvdial** is preinstalled on desktop version of Ubuntu.

**wvdial** uses a config file located `/etc/wvdial.conf`. Let's edit this file. Type in your terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/wvdial.conf
```

and you will see something like this

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2
Stupid Mode = yes
ISDN = 0
Modem Type = Analog Modem
New PPPD = yes
Phone = *99#
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB2
Username = ''
Password = ''
Baud = 9600
Dial Timeout = 30
Dial Attempts = 3
```

Explanation of all keys you can find in [wvdial.conf(5) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/5/wvdial.conf). If you need to change your provider dial number, username, password or any other information about connection and device you can change file content and save it.

There are 3 serial ports for **ZTE MF190**. Normally it's `ttyUSB0`, `ttyUSB1` and `ttyUSB2`. And in my case `ttyUSB2` is for internet connection. It would not work on other ports. So you need to find the right serial port for your modem.

There is an automatic configurator which edits **wvdial.conf** file, sets serial port baud rate etc. Since it is not always configure correctly I would **not recommend to use it**:

```
sudo wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

It would be better if you configure **wvdial** manually.

Now, when your device connected and **wvdial** configured to work with device, you can execute this line from terminal:

```
wvdial
```

You will see a lot of lines. But if you see those lines - you have succeeded.

```
local  IP address XX.XX.XX.XX
remote IP address XX.XX.XX.XX
primary   DNS address XX.XX.XX.XX
secondary DNS address XX.XX.XX.XX
```

Now, how we can use it in programming? I'll provide some code to work with it on Java. You can use this code to dial.

```
public int dialer() { 
    // status for debug. If status == 4 then you connected successfully
    int status; 
    // create process of wvdial
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("wvdial");

    try {
        // start wvdial
        final Process process = builder.start();

        // wvdial listener thread
        final Thread ioThread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(process.getErrorStream()));
                    // wvdial output line
                    String line;

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        // if "local  IP address" line detected set status 1
                        if (line.contains("local  IP address")) {
                            status = 1;
                        }
                        if (line.contains("remote IP address")) {
                            status = 2;
                        }
                        if (line.contains("primary   DNS address")) {
                            status = 3;
                        }
                        if (line.contains("secondary DNS address")) {
                            status = 4;
                        }
                    }

                    reader.close();
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                }
            }
        };
        // start listener
        ioThread.start();
        // wait 6 secs and return status. Some kind of timeout
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return status;
}
```

And here is a disconnector method. All you need is to kill **wvdial** process and thread will be destroyed:

```
public boolean disconnect() { 

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("pkill", "wvdial");
    try {
        builder.start();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a connection between the card and your provider is not sufficient. You need some mechanism for creating a network interface out of this connection, and set up your network stack to route packets over this interface.

Traditionally, the `pppd` daemon has been a popular choice for this task. You would create a "chat script" with the commands for establishing a data call (these days, `pppd` might come packaged with a suitable canned script) and the daemon would handle the entire process of placing the call, authenticating, setting up a network interface over the circuit, and configuring the system to route packets over it, as well as configuring DNS etc to use it for resolver queries, etc.

Comment: The last parts would probably be handled by DHCP once the interface is up. It's been a looooong time since I needed dialup.

Comment: But how can I explain modem to connect 2G/3G/4G this way?

Comment: Quick googling suggests something like [AT+ZSNT=0,0,2](http://unlockmodemfree.biz/zte-modem-at-commands-to-enable-disable-virtual-cd-rom-and-more/)

Comment: I googled about pppd. But not found how to connect with it. pppd help says that I need to use `connect` to connect seral line. But `pppd connect /dev/ttyUSB1` command has no response and no effect. How can I use pppd to connect serial port?

Comment: Try https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/3G_and_GPRS_modems_with_pppd for a general overview; most of it is not specific to Arch Linux, though you may need to make some adaptations for file locations etc.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to sniff USB port but on this case dashboard can not connect because of busy port

It is certainly possible. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/297892/trace-at-commands-to-a-modem)

> Found this article about [how to make data call](http://m2msupport.net/m2msupport/data-call-at-commands-to-set-up-gprsedgeumtslte-data-call/)

What that article is about is how to set up the call, not how to make it.
After you made correct setup, connect to internet with this command:
`ATD*99***1#`

**UPDATE1**: After a bit of research I believe that article was written only to promote their software and has no practical use. In reality dialing is made with `pppd` or `wvdial`

**UPDATE2**: We discussed ways to solve the problem in [a chat room (in Russian)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31003/room-for-leqada-and-oceinic). It turned out [cnetworkmanager](http://vidner.net/martin/software/cnetworkmanager/) will be the way to go

Comment: Anwer to `ATD*99***1#` is `CONNECT 7200000`. But ping shows 100% package loss. And OS cannot connect modem.

Comment: If I use pppd how can I explain modem to connect 2G/3G/4G...?

Comment: Since AT+ZSNT makes permanent changes you can run it manually in terminal. Another option is to add it into your chat scripts

Comment: I googled about pppd. But not found how to connect with it. pppd help says that I need to use `connect` to connect seral line. But `pppd connect /dev/ttyUSB1` command has no response and no effect. How can I use pppd to connect serial port?